# Angular JS controller and Factory in separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Web development and Angular are completely new to me. I have created module , factory and controller in a same file (app.js). Below is the sample code

```
//Main Module
var ipCharts = angular.module('ipCharts', []);

//Factory
ipCharts.factory('securityFactory', function ($http) {
    var securities = {};
    $http.get('api/Securities').
                                  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                      securities = data;
                                  }).
                                  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                      // log error
                                  });

    var factory = {};
    factory.getSecurities = function () {
        return securities;
    }
    return factory;
});

//Controller
ipCharts.controller('securityController', function ($scope,securityFactory) {
    $scope.securities = securityFactory.getSecurities();
});
```

I am wondering how module, factory and controller can be placed in separate files.

I can place the controller  in a separate file when the controller is not making any reference to the factory. I cant get it working when controller using the factory and the factory is in a separate file. 
Thanks

Comment: There should be no issue in putting them in separate files, so long as you load them in the correct order (i.e. modules script first, and then the other two whose order doesn't matter)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Include your main app file (in which you create the module) above the controller and factory files.

For retrieving pre-existing module:

```
var ipCharts = angular.module('ipCharts');
```

For controller file:

```
var ipCharts = angular.module('ipCharts');
ipCharts.controller('securityController', function ($scope,securityFactory) {
    $scope.securities = securityFactory.getSecurities();
});
```

For Factory file:

```
var ipCharts = angular.module('ipCharts');
ipCharts.factory('securityFactory', function ($http) {
    var securities = {};
    $http.get('api/Securities').
                                  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                      securities = data;
                                  }).
                                  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                      // log error
                                  });

    var factory = {};
    factory.getSecurities = function () {
        return securities;
    }
    return factory;
});
```

Comment: Your solution works  fine... Originally I have  var ipCharts = angular.module('ipCharts', []) in each file.

Comment: yes that is for creating new one, great to hear that it helped you :)